# Traverse DOM to select specific child for e2e test

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, testing, puppeteer

For my Angular application I am writing a simple script to test functionality of two buttons.  The html looks like so:

```
<body>

   <my-app _nghost-c0 ng-version="4.46">
     <mat-card _ngcontent-c) class="overflow mat-card">
       <div _ngcontent-c) class="login">...</div>
       <div _ngcontent-c) float-right>
         <button _ngcontent-c0> List Button </button>
         <button _ngcontent-c0> User Button </button>
       </div>
     </mat-card>
...
</body>
```

Because I do not have a CSS selector Id or Class for the two buttons I need to traverse the DOM to click them.  I have tried the following:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('login').children('button').click();
});
```

The issue with this approach is that it cannot find the node and in fact it has no way to find the specific button of 'List Button' or 'User Button'.  What is the simplest/cleanest way to traverse the DOM and click() on a specific button in this case.

Comment: You need to find the adjacent sibling's children not the login btn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find the children in the wrong parent element. You need to find the children in the element next to the login class. So based on the given DOM structure. The following will be the code snippet that will return you the btn elements

```
var loginElement = document.querySelectorAll('.login')[0];
var listBtn = loginElement.nextElementSibling.children[0];
var userBtn = loginElement.nextElementSibling.children[1];    

listBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
 console.log('listBtn clicked');
})

userBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
 console.log('userBtn clicked');
})

listBtn.click();
userBtn.click();
```

Comment: Ok, we have loginElement, but loginElement.nextElementSibling.children[0]; returns undefined.  If you look at the DOM structure, the buttons are not in the 'login' div, rather in the `<div _ngcontent-c) float-right>`

Comment: Nevermind I did this:  `let overflowDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.overflow')[0];
        let buttonDiv = overflowDiv.children[1];
        let listsButton = buttonDiv.children[0]; `